# Is there any shortcut to display all the fields of a model without explicitly specifying in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

We can create a model form very easily in Django just by passing a model form from *views* to the templates and displaying it as:

```
{{ form.as_table }}
```

Do we have similar way so that we do not have to type all the model's fields name in templates to display them?

Answer (score 2):

The models.Model class doesn't have a method similar to `.as_table()`.

You can use `.get_fields()` to make a similar thing. For example `Foo._meta.get_fields()` return a tuple of fields associated with the model `Foo`. Here is the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields).

The `key` is the field's type and the `value` is the field's name. You can loop in `value`s.